# "Could not read jar file contents from \FooBar\libs\android-support-v4.jar "?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I added the support library for API level 4 and up as is given in this link : http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

My code *was* working. But all of a sudden, it has started showing the following error :

`"Could not read jar file contents from \FooBar\libs\android-support-v4.jar"`

What could be the reason?

EDIT: It shows the following error too :

`"Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2`"

And a few more warnings like this ->

`"While loading class "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.GlobalProjectMonitor$IResourceEventListener", thread "Thread[main,6,main]" timed out waiting (5003ms) for thread "Thread[org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler,1,main]" to finish starting bundle "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395 [351]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[main,6,main]" is proceeding but "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.GlobalProjectMonitor$IResourceEventListener" may not be fully initialized."`

UPDATE : I thought I fixed it but the problem keeps recurring.

Comment: Right click on your project in Eclipse and go to Android Tools and select Add Support Library. See if this solves your issue.

Comment: Right click on project and select Fix Project Properties and .. Also configure the build path and clean build will make it work

Comment: Tried both suggestions. Not working:(

Comment: I am having the same problem. Code works, APK generates, Proguard works. App runs fine on multiple phones. Am getting red circle with white x (fatal error) indications for 3 libraries that are obviously in the build path and getting read.

Comment: I only get this when I try and export it using the signed packages in the android tools in eclipse